# PeopleSoft Purchasing 9.2 and Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, peoplesoft

Does PeopleSoft Purchasing 9.2 integrate with Docusign?

If Docusign does integrate with Purchasing 9.2 - will the local installation of Purchasing seamlessly integrate with the hosted Docusign?

I searched through Stackoverflow and couldn't find this information. If I missed anything accept my apologies. If any information is available regarding the integration between these two systems an URL would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently PeopleSoft does not have an integration with DocuSign. You may want to reach out to PeopleSoft to see if they have plans in the works.

Alternatively you may be able to build a custom integration that resides on your on-premise installation of PeopleSoft. I'm not sure how PeopleSoft handles 3rd party applications though.